# Сохранение выбранного пользователем адреса доставки через бесплатное API яндекс карт

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Появилась необходимость подключить карту на сайт. На этой карте должны быть отображены адреса пунктов выдачи Сдэк и по клику на пункт выдачи должно происходить сохранение адреса, выбранного пользователем. Вопрос в том, можно ли сохранять этот адрес при использовании бесплатного апи яндекс карт? 
Ссылка на условия использования апи: https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/geocoder/doc/desc/concepts/limits.html

Comment: Сохранить то можете, апи тут не причём

Comment: По условиям - https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/geocoder/doc/desc/concepts/limits.html, можно использовать получаемые координаты для отображения на карте или вычисления дистанции, например. Или использовать их при построении маршрута в оформлении доставки. Но хранение данных в собственных базах базовая лицензия не разрешает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вам уже верно отметили в комментариях, сохранение адреса, получаемого при клике на карту [пользовательским соглашением](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/terms/index-docpage/) Яндекса допускается только на [расширенных коммерческих тарифах](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/commercial/doc/concepts/jsapi-geocoder.html#jsapi-geocoder__tariff-plus). Сохранение координат, получаемых в результате поиска адреса, также недопустимо.

Вы можете лишь сохранить координаты, которые получены ручным выбором точки на карте, то есть фактически те, которые пользователь проставил сам. При последующем использовании адрес должен определяться каждый раз геокодированием этих координат.